# How should I understand left/right derivations of grammars and parse trees?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, parsers, derivation

I'm having a hard time understanding how left/right derivations work. I have a very simple example that I've attempted but I don't really know how to check if it's correct.

$S \to NP$ $V$ $NP$
$NP \to$ the $N$
$N \to$ cat | mouse
$V \to$ ate

**LEFT**

$S\to NP$ $V$ $NP$
$S\to$ the $N$ $V$ $NP$
$S\to$ the $N$ $V$ the $N$
$S\to$ the cat $V$ the $N$
$S\to$ the cat ate the $N$
$S\to$ the cat ate the mouse

**RIGHT**

$S\to NP$ $V$ $NP$
$S\to NP$ $V$ the $N$
$S\to$ the $N$ $V$ the $N$
$S\to$ the $N$ $V$ the mouse
$S\to$ the $N$ ate the mouse
$S\to$ the cat ate the mouse

**My Thoughts**

My lecture material says that we operate on the left/rightmost non terminal. I'm not 100% sure how to differentiate terminals and non-terminals but I assumed that if it became an English word it was a terminal hence I skipped it as long as there was a production remaining with another identifier in it.

**Parse Tree**

I know that the parse tree should be the same for the left and right derivation of the above grammar, just don't know how to build one. All examples I find online are too complex for my understanding. I just started learning about this stuff very recently. I genuinely don't know how to create the parse trees.

Answer (score 1):

A non-terminal is something with a production rule. You're correct that words aren't non-terminals. They are terminal precisely because there is no production which expands the word.

In a leftmost derivation, every step must expand the leftmost non-terminal. The leftmost non-terminal is the non-terminal which is closest to the left :-). In $\text{the N V NP}$ , the leftmost non-terminal is $\text{N}$. So if you choose a derivation step which expands $\text{NP}$, that's not a leftmost derivation.

In a parse tree, the root is whatever the root of the grammar is ($\text{S}$ in this case) and each node has as its children the symbols on the right-hand side of the production which is used the expand that particular non-terminal. Terminals are leaf nodes; they have no children.